# PHP: Why do Inherited Methods of Child Class access Parent's Private Properties?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, properties, parent-child

What a curious twist in PHP's property and method inheritance. See the following example:

```
class A {
    private $foo = 'hello';

    function get() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
    function set($val) {
        $this->foo = $val;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private $foo = 'world';

    function get() { // try inheriting this
        return $this->foo;
    }
    function set($val) {  // try inheriting this
        $this->foo = $val;
    }
}
```

Now let's see how that echoes out if we inherit or define methods:

```
$b = new B();

/* If B defines getter: */
echo $b->get(); // 'world' 

/* If B inherits getter: */
echo $b->get(); // 'hello'

// Enter Setter!
$b->set('cosmos');

/* If B defines setter & inherits getter: */
echo $b->get(); // 'hello' 

/* If B inherits setter & defines getter: */
echo $b->get(); // 'world' 

/* If B defines or inherits both: */
echo $b->get(); // 'cosmos'
```

So: When class B defines the getter, it returns its own private `$foo` ( `= "world"`). However if I remove the getter from class B, and class B inherits the very same method from class A, it returns instead the private `$foo` property from the parent class A (`= "hello"`) instead. Likewise with setters.

I was expecting inherited methods to access the properties of the instantiated class at all times, with no reference to their ancestors' private properties. They are private for a reason, no? Private with side-effects! If I change the prop visibility to public or protected, the expected properties "world" and "cosmos" from class B are returned, whether methods are defined or inherited.

---

Here are object dumps for each of the above cases:

```
var_dump($b);

/* If B defines getter (Prop get from B): */

["foo":"B":private] · string(5) "world"
["foo":"A":private] · string(5) "hello"

/* If B inherits getter: (Prop get from A) */

["foo":"B":private] · string(5) "world"
["foo":"A":private] · string(5) "hello"

// Enter Setter!
$b->set('cosmos');

/* If B defines setter & inherits getter 
 * Prop set to B & get from A */

["foo":"B":private] · string(6) "cosmos"
["foo":"A":private] · string(5) "hello"

/* If B defines getter & inherits setter
 * :: Prop set to A & get from B */

["foo":"B":private] · string(5) "world"
["foo":"A":private] · string(6) "cosmos"

/* If B defines both:
 * :: Prop set to B & get from B */

["foo":"B":private] · string(6) "cosmos"
["foo":"A":private] · string(5) "hello"

/* If B inherits both:
 * :: Prop set to A & get from A: */

["foo":"B":private] · string(5) "world"
["foo":"A":private] · string(6) "cosmos"
```

Can someone explain to me the logic in what's going on? Are inherited property-access methods bound to the private properties of the original method-defining parent class? I'd rather not copy-paste the same method into each child class that has private properties with a matching name.

Excuse me if the illustrations above go on ad nauseam. Had to spell this out for my own sanity huh -- unexpected behavior, unless I'm missing something obvious. (N.B. Having constructors or invoking `parent::__construct()` in the child class constructor has no impact on this behavior.)

---

**Add:** Now one step further. If I declare the getters protected, and create a public method in class B for getting variables. Like so:

```
class B {...
    public function getpro_direct() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
    public function getpro_getter() {
        return $this->get();
    }
...}

echo $b->getpro_direct(); // "world" (from B)
echo $b->getpro_getter(); // "hello" (from A)
```

And if I inherit these two methods from A instead, I get `"hello"` on both counts. But if I define a `get()` in B, I get "hello" and "world" respectively. Hello world hello, cosmos calling. I need some juice.

---

**Edit** for those of you wondering why I'm at this. The short background story: I'm working on a class hierarchy that grows in more depth in (array) properties, with each child class being a less abstract version down the same vector. (Spare you the examples.) I'm working out the smartest way to merge the child's extended properties with each consecutive parent's basis.

Private declaration was so far the only way to prevent the child class from overwriting the parent's properties, as I could have the properties of both simultaneously available via using the parent getter. That however mucks up the method inheritance, as illustrated here. I'd like to get this done as automagically as possible; preferably with a single `clone_parent()` method that's inherited and run in each child's constructor. I'd rather avoid spelling out separate cloners for each parent-child extension hop. (I've searched and read around a bunch here, yet to find a satisfactory solution.)

**Edit2:** Other approaches pending, on my actual concern (as above) that led to this experiment. To keep things simple, I'll just ditch the overlapping declaration in the child's properties and call an `extend_props` method that adds atop the props inherited from the arent. (Alas I hoped to have each extending class's extras shown pretty up atop, instead of lurking down below inside a method!)

Comment: Whether you agree with it or not, this is expected behaviour afaik, and the reason for that is because that's how it's built. As to why it was built like that... well... who knows. But to me it does make sense, but perhaps that is just PHP turning me mad.

Comment: You wrote that it's *curious* - does this imply that private properties behave differently in other OO languages such as C# or Java?

Comment: @JonStirling If that's the way it's built, alrighty-right... seems to me that it makes inheritance a lot more complicated, if you use private properties with the same names in child classes. Short version as I see it is, **we can't inherit methods that access private properties**.

Comment: @N.B. I have no idea how this works in other languages. It's curious to me because it will force me to redefine identical methods in child classes, and that seems a redundant duplication of code. Especially if the same class pattern is inherited for several generations onward. I imagine the need to access a parent's private properties is less common than the need to inherit methods that access the private properties of the prop-defining class.

Comment: I'm not suprised about the visibility behavior about between both object. The most surprisingly IMHO is the interpreter let you implement two variables with same name in the inheritance even the properties are protected or public (I've tested here).

Comment: If you made something `private` then that means you understand how it will behave during inheritance. When developing interfaces for something, sometimes you want to disallow child classes modifying the core functionality, therefore you make properties `private` and you create methods that can change or access those properties. Doing so, you're forcing that everything "goes through" a set of methods that can implement required checks before altering something that you deem necessary. This is normal behavior and I smell an XY problem here.

Comment: It seems that you won't have this problem if you don't redeclare the private properties in the child classes. Why would you need to do that anyway?

Comment: After all, it's has been about the scope of $this and the visibility between objects. If the proterties are protectes or publics, the property from A will never been in touch (at least in your example).

Comment: @GabrielHeming now that you mention, I notice the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php notes (in the sample code comment), "We can redeclare the public and protected method, but not private". I see both parent and child private props in object dumps. So both are there, but they must be accessed differently (ie. parent props by inherited setter, and child props `->`directly.)

Comment: It seems like the proper way to define B in order for the inheritance to work properly is just `class B extends A { }` without redeclaring any of it. Isn't that part of the point of inheritance, after all?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm chewing on a class hierarchy that grows in more depth in (array) properties, with each child class being a less abstract version of the same vector. (Spare you the examples.) Working out the smartest way to merge the child's ext. properties with each consecutive parent's basis. Private declaration was so far the only way to prevent the child from overwriting the parent's property. I'd like to get it done as automagically as possible; preferably with a single `clone_parent()` method that's inherited and run in each child's constructor. But that's obviously not happening here.

Comment: This behavior is completely sane. If the private visibility means that **only the same class that declared it can use it**, then why are you expecting `A`'s getter to get the private property of `B`? The other question why you declare a property as private, if you need to access it in the child? Private properties are **private** because they **should be used only inside given class and mean something only inside the given class**.

Comment: @sevavietl yeah it is sane, now that I chew on it. What's missing, as far as my actual concern, is somehow accessing the parent's (any visibility) properties in an extending class that defines identically named properties (and overwrites the parent's when instantiated). (Necessary because I really don't want to have different prop names and separate get-sets for each damned child that works the same domain.) I've edited the post with more on this.

Comment: @MarkusAO, and that's why composition is preferred over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

`Private properties` are `not accessible outside his own class`.

If you're extending a class, they aren't accessible outside too. The reason that you "see the private property of the parent" is that you've defined a `getter` in the parent. This getter has access to the private property, because he is in the same class. It's not strange.

I suggest you to read more about `private`, `protected` and `public`.

Comment: Actually if I remove the private property from class B, and then dump it, the private property from A is still there in the dump: `B Object [ [foo:A:private] => hello]`. So it's obviously inherited on some (inaccessible) level. I know I can get a parent's private property with a getter in the parent class. What I'm chewing here is the conflict between identically named private properties in both parent and child classes.

Comment: @MarkusAO Yes, I get your point, but it's not a right approach. Anyway, I prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: Yeah this is clearly not the way to go. I ended up experimenting with this after reading a thread here, where someone suggested a means to clone a parent's properties by private declaration etc. (See the edit for my original concern.) Felt like a hack but was worth giving a shot -- nothing lost, more learned about private properties. Back to the design patterns drawing board then. :)